# Data Conversion in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to concatenate 2 columns and show as a single field in my stored procedure.

```
Column Batch - int 
Column AdmissionNo - nvarchar
```

I tried querying like so

```
select (a.AdmissionNo + ' - ' + a.BatchID) as RollNo
```

But I get the following error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_GetAdmittedStudents, Line 7
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '13-01 - ' to data type int.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both column datatypes must be same or casted to same type.

```
select (a.AdmissionNo + ' - ' + CAST(a.BatchID as nvarchar) ) as RollNo
```

**Note :**

All `int` datatype values can be casted to `varchar / nvarchar` but not vice versa.
So its safer to CAST int column to varchar/nvarchar

Comment: could you please elaborate? I am kind of new to SQL.

Comment: check now , i am assuming batchID is of type int